# Android RecyclerView how to open new activity from clicking the items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

***Hello guys, someone can help me to finish this simple project, please?
I don't know how to configure the click on the items for opening a new activities.***

**RecycleViewAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ModelData> users;
private Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ModelData> users, Context context) {
    this.users = users;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ModelData user = users.get(position);
    holder.nomeUser.setText(user.getName());
    holder.userImage.setImageResource(user.getUserImage());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView nomeUser;
    private ImageView userImage;


    public ViewHolder( View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nomeUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomeText);
        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        context = itemView.getContext();

    }


}
```

**ModelData.java**

```
package com.example.aicopolilattico.splashscreen;

import java.security.PublicKey;

public class ModelData {

private String name;
private int userImage;

public ModelData() {}

public ModelData(String name, int userImage ) {

    this.name = name;
    this.userImage = userImage;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getUserImage() {
    return userImage;
}
```

**ActivityMain.java**

```
package com.example.aicopolilattico.splashscreen;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ActivityMan extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recycleView;
private List<ModelData> users;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityone);

    recycleView = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    users = new ArrayList<>();

    users.add(new ModelData("Jack and Jones", R.drawable.jackcjones111));
    users.add(new ModelData("Marlboro", R.drawable.marlb));

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recycleView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    recycleView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(users, this));
    recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);


}
```

**Guys is really important.
Thanks in advance to have patience and time to give me. :)**

***[ ! ! ! UPDATES ! ! ! ]***

I've tried to write the code below, but when I click on the item, it pick up me on the first activity of the app. Advices? Thank a lot

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
{


private List<ModelData> users;
private Context context;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ModelData> users, Context context)
{
    this.users = users;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_row, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    final ModelData user = users.get(position);
    holder.nomeUser.setText(user.getName());
    holder.userImage.setImageResource(user.getUserImage());
    holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Photo_Man.class);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}


@Override
public int getItemCount()
       {
    return users.size();
       }




public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    private TextView nomeUser;
    private ImageView userImage;


    public ViewHolder( View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        nomeUser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomeText);
        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        context = itemView.getContext();



    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry but Stackoverflow is not a "please code this for me" community.

Comment: Possibly duplicate please see this link [Recyclerview Item Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43962027/on-click-recyclerview-go-to-another-activity-with-data-in-android/43962215#43962215)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u replace click listener like below code

```
    holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Photo_Man.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have to implement onClickListner on the OnBindViewHolder method or in the complete RecyclerViewAdapter.class?

Comment: Sorry, useless answer, apologize

Comment: OnBindViewHolder  method. it's not working then can u share photo_man.class code

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to achieve that is sending a listener of that event from the activity to the recyclerview.

Something like this...

1. Create an interface for listening click events:

   ```
   public interface OnItemClickListener {
       void onItemClick();
   }
   ```
2. Modify the adapter to receive the listener:

   ```
   private OnItemClickListener listener;

   public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<ModelData> users, Context context, OnItemClickListener listener ) {
       this.users = users;
       this.context = context;
       this.listener = listener;
   }
   ```
3. Create listener from activity (From here you can open new activities):

   ```
   OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override public void onItemClick() {
           Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityMain.this, NewActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   };
   ```
4. Send that interface to the adapter:

   ```
   recycleView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(users, this, listener));
   ```
5. Set this listener to the views you want to observe the event:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder( ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       ModelData user = users.get(position);
       holder.nomeUser.setText(user.getName());
       holder.userImage.setImageResource(user.getUserImage());
       holder.userImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override public void onClick(View v) {
               listener.onItemClick();
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm embarassed to ask you this but, where I should write the point 3? And for the next items I have to use "intent1, intent2 ... " or it's an automatic choise of the method ?

Comment: The 3rd and 4th is in the current activity where the ReyclerView is showed. The 5th point is inside the adapter. In this case every click on the ImageView trigger the same Intent. If you need just modify that interface to send some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

First go to you recyclerview adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method.

Then simply add below code. here `itemView` is the particular one item of recyclerview

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you go for second activity using intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class); // here you need context from constructor, SecondActivity is another activity
            context.startActivity(intent); // this will call the SecondActivity intent
            ((Activity)context).finish(); // this is for just finish current activity (OPTIONAL, as per requirement)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nothing to do, when I click on the items the app pick up me back to the main activity :/

Comment: Ok, tell me which activity you pass in the intent ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to goto activity

```
  holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {      


          Intent intent = new Intent(context,SomeActivity.class); 

        context.startActivity(intent); 

            }
        });
```

if you want to goto fragment

```
   holder.nomeUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.transaction,get_posts).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
```